# Parsing data from .txt file using VBA, data and variable on different line

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, text

I have a .txt file that changes the format it is displayed in for certain variables

I am able to successfully extract time data using this code:

File data:

```
+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Start Time      | 09/06/2015 02:28:58                                              |
| Finish Time     | 09/06/2015 03:12:33                                              |
+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Code:

```
'open .txt files from defined folder(s)
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\Localdata\XYZ").Files
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "txt" Then
      'define Row
      Row = Row + 1
      'open each file as a text stream and read until end of file
      Set stream = f.OpenAsTextStream
      Do While Not stream.AtEndOfStream
        Line = stream.ReadLine
        'extract the data associated with the text for items in data line
        If InStr(1, Line, "Start Time") Then
        'Add each value to the next available row in designated column (A,B...)
           Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Trim(Split(Line, "|")(2))
        End If
```

But, now I'm trying parse data that appears in the file in this manner:

```
|                                 |                   Variable                 |
|                                 +-----------+-----------+--------+-----------+
|            Object               |  Value1   |  Value2   | Value3 |  Value4   |
|                                 |           |           |        |           |
+=================================+===========+===========+========+===========+
| Type                            |     5.00 |     10.00  |   15.00|     20.00 |
+---------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

I'd like to flag off the text "Variable" and pull the value under Value2 (10.00).
I have several "tables" like this in the text file with variable spacing and character length

How can I get it to skip down a few rows from the text string of interest?

Comment: First idea come to mind is to use a variable to store which mode when the line is read, say `If InStr(1,Line,"Variable",vbTextCompare) > 0 Then bLookForValue = True`, so from next line, different test cases for items in splitting `|` and use `Len(...) > 0`, `IsNumeric(...)` to pick up values, when value retrieved, `bLookForValue = False`. It may also help to remove empty spaces for each Line.

Comment: Is "Value2" always in the same location or do you need to find that first before extracting the value from the following line?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's messy.  In this example, Value2 will always be in that location, and may repeat several times in the file. But there are additional tables with data I am interested in. In these cases, value2 may be in a different row or position in the line. To make it worse, some tables do not have unique column headers, so there may be multiple "Value" strings. This is why I need to somehow key off of "Variable" for text. Numerically, the data value is also not always unique.

Comment: Tim: thank you also for fixing the table display in my post. How did you do that?

Comment: I used the code sample `{}` button.

Comment: Would be useful if you could post a larger sample, or provide more detail about exactly what you need to parse.  Otherwise, @PatricK's advise is more or less how you should proceed.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with VBA. To understand Patrick's suggestion. Can someone provide an example of one test scenario for items in splitting | and using Len and IsNuemeric commands? The piece of code I'm using wasn't mine originally. I found it on a forum and modified it. But, I'm stuck if the data value and the text string I'm keying off of are on different lines.

Answer (score 1):

I had friend help me out with this problem and we found that the only way to extract the exact data I wanted was to key off unique text and then off of the +--- characters that defined the table:

```
If InStr(1, LineTxt, "Variable", vbTextCompare) Then ' Look For unique text in desired table - this starts the next search for "Object"

    a = 0 'Use this as a switch for breaking out of next DO LOOP

Do While a <> 1 'Do this unti a = 1

    Line Input #1, LineTxt ' Read line from

    If InStr(1, LineTxt, "+==========") Then ' Look for Type - This only occurs after "Object" is found, so it will not happen other time "Type" occurs in the log.
    Line Input #1, LineTxt ' read a line on each loop
    Row = Row + 1 ' Increment counter for row
       Worksheets("Output").Range("J60000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Trim(Split(LineTxt, "|")(3)) 'Once "Type" is found, split the line and write the data to a cell on worksheet "Output"

    a = 1 ' Set swith to 1 - The Do / While loop will break due to this switch change.
    End If
Loop ' Loop until a = 1
```

End If

Thanks to everyone that did provide suggestions.  I learned a lot on this forum!